# How to use tryCatch() to ignore the error in while loop in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, while-loop

I have a code that reads each line of my dataframe's first column, visits the website and then downloads the photo of each deputy. But it doesn't work properly because there are some deputies who don't have a photo yet.

That's why my code breaks and stop working. I tried to use "next" and if clauses, but it still didn't work. So a friend recomended me to use the tryCatch(). I couldn't find enough information online, and the code still doesn't work.

The file is here:
https://gist.github.com/gabrielacaesar/940f3ef14eaf29d18c3780a66053bbee

```r
deputados <- fread("dep-legislatura56-14jan2019.csv")

i <- 1

while(i <= 514) {
  this.could.go.wrong <- tryCatch(
  attemptsomething(),
  error=function(e) next
  )
  url <- deputados$uri[i]
  api_content <- rawToChar(GET(url)$content)
  pessoa_info <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_content)
  pessoa_foto <- pessoa_info$dados$ultimoStatus$urlFoto
  download.file(pessoa_foto, basename(pessoa_foto), mode = "wb")
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write trycatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Comment: It's not duplicated, it's a tryCatch() inside a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap `tryCatch` on the lines that can potentially raise errors and have it return `NULL` or `NA` on the *error* block:

```
i <- 1

while(i <= 514) {
   tryCatch({
      url <- deputados$uri[i]
      api_content <- rawToChar(GET(url)$content)
      pessoa_info <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_content)
      pessoa_foto <- pessoa_info$dados$ultimoStatus$urlFoto
      download.file(pessoa_foto, basename(pessoa_foto), mode = "wb")
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }, error = function(e) return(NULL)
   )
   i <- i + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

download_picture <- function(url){
  api_content <- rawToChar(httr::GET(url)$content)
  pessoa_info <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_content)
  pessoa_foto <- pessoa_info$dados$ultimoStatus$urlFoto
  download.file(pessoa_foto, basename(pessoa_foto), mode = "wb")
}

walk(deputados$uri, possibly(download_picture, NULL))
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the wrong post? I can't see a tryCatch anywhere.

Comment: @NelsonGon - `purrr::possibly` is simply a wrapper for `tryCatch`, so this seems relevant

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!