# How to get correct website URL from a redirect in R?

Tags: r, url, redirect

Beginner here, I have a list (or rather column) full of website redirect URLs from which I want to get the "correct" website URL. Example, I have the URL https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A//sirinlabs.com%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder but I want to get the correct website URL https://sirinlabs.com/?utm_source=icoholder that appears in the search bar when you click the previous link and load the website.

Any idea how to manage this is in R for an entire column of these URLs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `httr` library to get the final URL

```
url <- "https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A//sirinlabs.com%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder"
httr::GET(url)$url
# [1] "https://sirinlabs.com/?utm_source=icoholder"
```

That will actually make the HTTP request to see where the server sends you.

If you want to assume that the correct URL will always be in the `?to=` querystring parameter, you can use

```
httr::parse_url(url)$query$to
[1] "https://sirinlabs.com?utm_source=icoholder"
```

without making any sort of HTTP request.

Comment: Great, thank you! How do I adapt this code to do this for an entire column of such urls?

Comment: You can `sapply` or `purrr:map` over the list of URLs using which ever method is more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: sorry for the follow-up questions: Could the code for this look like this? ```library(httr) df$Website_URL <- sapply(df$Website_URL, GET)``` if df$Website_URL the column including the urls? This does not seem to work, any idea what I need to change?

Comment: You need to extract the url part of the response object `df$Website_URL <- sapply(df$Website_URL, function(x) GET(x)$url)`

Comment: With this I get the error ```Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Could not resolve host: ico.trecento-blockchain.capital```

Comment: That's seems to be a bad URL. Sounds like some of the websites in your list aren't real. If you have bad data, you may need to wrap the request in a try-catch block: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241933/how-to-use-trycatch-to-ignore-the-error-in-while-loop-in-r

Comment: That makes sense! Could you help me with the correct code as I am not sure how to incorporate the tryatch since I have never used it before? Otherwise I will open up a new question

Comment: The link I already provided has an example of using a `tryCatch`. Have you tried that yet? Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Comment: Yes I tried, however I am not sure how to adapt the code to my example with the dataframe. I found the other example as well but there they are using a vector of urls, not a column. I am quite new to R so I am not sure how to adapt the code